# How to fix 502 error when running Python scripts on IIS CGI

Tags: python, iis, import, package, cgi

I have an issue running python script when import any packages that didn't come with python 3.9 by default. Details below:

- IIS 10 running on Windows server 2019
- Python 3.9.7 installed under C:\Program Files\Python397
- Packages are under C:\Program Files\Python397\lib\site-packages
- I went thru all steps to configure IIS to run python with Handler Mappings, etc.
- Security set for IUSR full control for python install folder and the IIS folder (/pyapp)
- When tested with simple forms (like https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm) and it works good on browser.

Here's the problem - I have a new .py script with the content below. When run on browser it gives me the infamous error "502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server." because of the "**import requests**" line. If I remove that line (**import requests**) then it works fine. All packages, like this "requests" has been installed properly and works fine in Jupyter Notebook. I heard that IIS runs on a diff acct (IUSR?) and cannot access this site-package folder so I added here but not working. I also add these paths in the system path, no help either. Thanks for your help!

```py
import sys

import os

import site

site.addsitedir(r'C:\Program Files\Python397\lib\site-packages')

sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files\Python397\lib\site-packages')

import requests
   

print('Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n')

print('html tags here')
```

Comment: maybe you have two Python installed and it runs code with Python which don't have installed `requests`. In HTML you could display `sys.executable` to check if it runs correct Python.

Comment: run python directly and check `requests.__file__` to see path to file with this module. Maybe it is in different folder.

Comment: Hi Furas, in HTML when I ran print(sys.executable) I got this output:
C:\Program Files\Python397\python.exe 
which is the python install directory.

Comment: I cannot run requests.__file__ in html due to the error as described, but in Jupyter Notebook I got the output: 

C:\Program Files\Python397\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py

Comment: you could put `import` in `try/except` to catch error message, and display it in HTML (in place of `"html tags here"`. Maybe this gives some information why it has problem with `requests`.

Comment: Thanks @furas - I put try/except and here's the error output on browser:
       No module named 'urllib3'

Comment: maybe `urllib3` is in different folder and you have to add it to `sys.path`

Comment: When I go do "pip install urllib3" it says "Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in c:\users\username\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (1.26.8)" which is a different folder than my default install folder 'C:\Program Files\Python397\lib\site-packages'

Comment: I tried the following but still got the 502 error:

sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages');
import requests

Comment: do you get the same error message? Maybe it need another module.

Comment: you may also try to use `--update` in `pip install --update ...` and it should reinstall it - but it may install again in the same folder.

Comment: OK yes that's exactly what I just did and it DID SOLVE THE PROBLEM. Thanks to your suggestion putting the try/except in the html code so I can see clearly what the error is, and those packages were install in a diff folder. I ran pip uninstall to remove those in the admin cmd window, then pip install them again, now they are installed in the appropriate folder and my python script no longer has 502 error. I will continue to do this for the rest of other packages. THANK YOU SO MUCH @furas ! Your're awesome!

Comment: you can describe it as answer (below), and mark as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @furas for your help. The root cause was that, for some reason when I pip installed those packages, they were installed under diff folder (user roaming folder) instead of under the folder where python is installed. The exception errors can be seen when we put the import statement in the try/except block in the html output section. I pip uninstalled them and reinstall, and now they are installed under the python folder. My python cgi scripts runs good on the web browser now. Thanks again.